# Javascript to capture shortcut and run some action

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events

I need to capture the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> (for example) to open a document with the same name except the extension with Javascript.

In order to do that, I need to do those three steps.

1. Catch the <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>
2. get document name
3. replace the name

What functions/methods can I use to implement them?

```
document.onkeypress=function(e){
    String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) == 'e' and Alt is pressed ??
    get document name ??
    newwindow = replace the html to txt ??
    window.open(newwindow,"myWindow");
}
```

### ADDED

I couldn't make Apple's command to work, but I could open TextMate with 'Control-E'.

```
var isCtrl = false;
document.onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
}
document.onkeydown=function(e){
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 69 && isCtrl == true) {
        window.location = "txmt://open/?url=file://%s","myWindow";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't change the semantics of standard shortcuts -- Alt+E opens the Edit menu in most browsers, so don't make it do something else.

Comment: @casablanca : Thanks for the comment, I just want to capture shortcut and do something.

Answer (score 2):

See this example on how to use keycodes to determine if combinations are pressed (Alt, Cntr, Shift + something). It also has a list of all keycodes at the bottom.

[How to create Ctrl+Key shortcuts in Javascript](http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/126/how-to-create-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-javascript/)

There is also a native `event.ctrlKey`, `event.shiftKey`,`event.altKey` property you can use.

That said, consider using SHIFT as your modifier so that it doesn't clash with anything else. CNTR and ALT tend to be common combos used by menus and scrolling (CNTR + mouse scroll === zoom for example).

Answer (score 1):

the event has a altKey atribute, if alt key is press its true, just add

```
if(e.altkey && String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) == 'e'){
 DoSomething()
}
```

Comment: `String.fromCharCode` nice. Thanks for that little snippet.